# Firebase. Is it safe to grant access to client to write into database on server directly?

Tags: javascript, security, firebase-realtime-database

I am exploring Google Firebase. And from docs I see that they grant access to client to change database on server directly... Is this safe?

```
private void WriteNewScore(string userId, int score)
{
    // Create new entry at /user-scores/$userid/$scoreid and at /leaderboard/$scoreid simultaneously
    string key = mDatabase.Child("scores").Push().Key;
    LeaderBoardEntry entry = new LeaderBoardEntry(userId, score);
    Dictionary<string, Object> entryValues = entry.ToDictionary();

    Dictionary<string, Object> childUpdates = new Dictionary<string, Object>();
    childUpdates["/scores/" + key] = entryValues;
    childUpdates["/user-scores/" + userId + "/" + key] = entryValues;

    mDatabase.UpdateChildrenAsync(childUpdates);
}
```

What if client can be "emulated" or hacked etc. Should one use AppEngine with REST-Interface which implements server-side secure logic for changing database or working with databases directly is right and safe way here? Or are there any specific solutions to keep databases in Firebase safe? Thanks.

Docs page: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data

Comment: They only have access to the node that you configure for that user and only in the context of the application in which it is deployed, this because nobody can directly access your database without authentication. In the same way you must configure the authentication method and the security rules that will govern the connection to your Firebase database

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a [security rules language for the Firebase Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/), that allows you to describe validation and access rules for your data. With the correct rules in place, this can be just as secure as any server-side code you'd write yourself.

For example, with the snippet of code you shared, you'll want to:

- Validate that the score written is of the right format, and that it falls into the expected range.
- Validate that the `/scores/$key` and `/user-scores/$uid/$key` are the same values.
- Ensure that a user can only write under their own `$uid`.

Such rules and many more are covered in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/) and in [many previous question on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-database+firebase-security).

You can do really advanced things in these security rules. For example, I've seen somebody validate chess moves, and someone else build a secure player-to-player buy/sell system in these rules.

But the tolerance for writing such rules varies from developer to developer. Many developers are more used to doing such (validation and access) logic in imperative code, in which case using custom server-side code is fine too. If that's your preference, I recommend that you check out [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/), which makes this easy and integrates nicely with many Firebase products (such as the realtime database).